# TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have updated visual studio 2012 last night, this was Visual Studio 2012 Update 4. It was working fine before but now i am unable to connect with tfs server. Please let me know what i am doing wrong?

This is the error:

```
    TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server     https://myServer.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection.
Technical information (for administrator):
  Unable to connect to the remote server
```

Comment: See this link if it helps: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613214/TF400324-Team-Foundation-services-are-not-availabl

Answer (score 15):

try clearing your cache folder?

C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation

TFS3 is VS2010, TFS4 is VS2012, TFS5 is VS2013

---

Stop all instances of Visual Studio.

Zip/Rar all the files as a backup, then delete all files except for the backup zip/rar.

Restart Visual Studio and it will recreate all the files and you should be able to connect as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Worked today for VS2015

Answer (score 3):

I followed this steps to get rid of this issue:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio.
2. Open the Task Manager and check if any TFS Services are running. Select each of them and click on End Process Tree.
3. Browse to the folder below and delete all the contents and folders in

   ```
   %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache
   ```

   and in

   ```
   %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache
   ```
4. Restart Visual Studio and try triggering build.
5. If you are switching from one version of TFS to another, you may require repeating this solution again.  If you are using older version of TFS, you may have to navigate to

%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\
and find out the version folder instead of navigating directly. It would be 
`TFS3` if using `VS2010`, `TFS4` if using `VS2012`, `TFS5` if using `VS2013`.

Source: [TF400324: Team Foundation Services are not available from server](http://www.ganshani.com/blog/2014/03/solved-tf400324-team-foundation-services-are-not-available-from-server/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case clearing of cache folders didn't work out.

What I also did is enabling SSL in IIS for Team Foundation Server.

Hopefully, StartSSL.com can offer it for free.
Step by step:

On server side:

1. Cleare cache folders like it described above;
2. Get the SSL following procedure described [here](http://blog.dampee.be/post/2013/03/12/How-to-install-a-FREE-startssl-certificate-on-your-IIS-7x.aspx);
3. Enable SSL for Team foundation server in IIS (netmgr);
4. Check if your TFS server is available over https (check link https://tfs.your-server, the certificate should be valid and page opened without any warnings);

On client side:

1. Remove all TFS servers in Visual Studio;
2. Add your TFS server connection with HTTPS (not HTTP).

Now you are able to work with VS-TFS link.

Answer (score 0):

If the above methods don't work, and in the `Output` tab shows you have to contact the server administrator, then the TFS is actually down and you are disconnected to it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but the problem still appeared in VS 2013 and TFS 2013.

In my case the IIS on the server side was not running. After starting it VS could immediate connect again.